# How do I read streams other than stdout, stdin from a subproccess with Popen?

Tags: python, c, ipc, popen

```py
import subprocess

popen = subprocess.Popen("./test1", stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)

for line in iter(popen.stdout.readline, ""):
    print(line, end="")
```

this is how I would read if I wrote to stdout, in the popen class it seems to not have an option for these

```c
    while (true)
    {
#define out_video_stream 3
#define out_audio_stream 4

        res = decode_frame(input1, frame, packet);
        
        switch (input1->container->streams[packet->stream_index]->codecpar->codec_type)
        {

        case AVMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO:
            write(out_video_stream, frame->data[0], frame->linesize[0] * frame->height);
            break;

        case AVMEDIA_TYPE_AUDIO:
            write(out_audio_stream, frame->data[0], frame->nb_samples * frame->channels);
            break;

        default:
            continue;
        }

        if (res == 1)
        {
            printf("error decoding frame\n");
            return 1;
        }
        else if (res == -1)
        {
            printf("File ended\n");
            break;
        }
    }
```

This is how I write to stream number 3 and 4

How do I access this 2 streams from python

Comment: I think you can do it with [`os.mkfifo`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.mkfifo). See question [Python subprocess hangs with named pipes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19859283/python-subprocess-hangs-with-named-pipes).

Comment: maybe `stdout=open(3)`